# Jython and Python Lib Dependencies

Tags: python, maven, dependencies, jython

I am contributing on an open source Java project, and I am trying to use the Python tool ObsPy via the Jython PythonInterpreter. My problem is that I am having trouble figuring out how to include the ObsPy library in the Jython buildpath. Is it possible to use Maven in order to include the ObsPy library in a manner that the Jython runtime will recognize it?

Thanks, and sorry I could not provide any existing code on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

ObsPy relies on `ctypes` which works only for CPython - so I'm afraid you won't get it running under Jython.